# Non linear first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a differential equation of the type $x''=-x+x^3$. Now when I first integrate it with respect to time, $t$, then I am getting $x'=x(x^2-1)+C$, which is a non-linear first order differential equation.
Now if the constant happens to be zero then I can solve it by partial fraction method but as life is not easier that constant term tagged to the $x'$ is actually not zero. So how to proceed forward in this case.

Thank you...

Comment: Hey where is the other answer to my answer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with:
$${\frac {d^{2}}{d{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right) = x \left( t
 \right)  ^{3}-x \left( t \right) \tag{1}$$
substitute:
$$x \left( t \right) ={\frac {\sqrt{2}\,k\,y \left( t \right)}{ \sqrt{(1+{k}^{
2})}}}$$
into $(1)$ and then rename the variable to:
$$ t=T\sqrt{1+k^2}$$
and you get the equation for the [Jacobi elliptic sn function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions) :
$${\frac {d^{2}}{d{T}^{2}}}y \left( T \right) -2\,  y \left( T
 \right)   ^{3}{k}^{2}+ \left( 1+{k}^{2} \right) y \left( T
 \right)$$ 
which has solution:
$$y(T)=sn(T+\tau_0,k)$$
and you are free to pick the value for the elliptic modulus $k$ and starting value $\tau_0$ as these are your two free parameters for the second order differential equation. Back substitution then gives:
$$x \left( t \right) ={\frac {\sqrt {2}k}{\sqrt {1+{k}^{2}}}sn\left( {\frac {t}{\sqrt {
1+{k}^{2}}}}+{\it \tau_0},k \right) }$$
You will recover an elementary function if you chose $k=1$ and you get:
$$x \left( t \right) =\tanh \left( \frac{t}{\sqrt {2}}+\tau_0\right) $$
as you are aware.

Comment: Hey tons of thanks for the answer but how did you get the substitution for the $x(t)$?

Comment: From experience I recognised an elliptic function differential equation. To read off the solution you have to manipulate the equation to match the well known form, there are a few basic tricks rescaling the function shifting the function (adding a constant) e.t.c.. there was no need to add a constant in this instance so rescaling the variable and the function suffices, putting in starting guesses e.g. $x(t)=a y(t)$ and $T=bt$ you then look at the equation again and solve for those unkowns $a,b$ in terms of $k$ to match the coefficients in the more familiar form.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying your equation by $x'$ and using the facts that $x''x'=(\frac{x'^2}{2})'$, 
 $xx'=(\frac{x^2}{2})'$ and  $x^3x'=(\frac{x^4}{4})'$, where primes represents the derivatives w.r.t. $t$,  and interating the resulting equation you get

$\frac{x'^2}{2}= \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4}$ (we have taken $c_1=0$),

or $x'= \pm\sqrt{x^2-\frac{x^4}{2}}$ or $\pm\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-\frac{x^4}{2}}}=dt$ or 
 $\pm\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-\frac{x^4}{2}}}=t$ ($c_2=0$). Evaluation of the integral (by trigonometric substitution $x=\sqrt{2}\sin\theta$) gives you the result. We have chosen constants of integration for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Now you have substituted $x=\sqrt{2}sin(t)$ in here but when you substitute this back in main equation because you can't have two expression for the $x(t)$ then that equation is not satisfying. So i think that's basically wrong but the way you calculated $\dot{x}$ I got that. Thanks

Comment: blusquare it is a typo. Of course it should be $x=\sqrt{2}\sin\theta$. After this substitution your integral to be $\int\csc\theta d\theta=\ln|cot\theta-\csc\theta|+c$.

Comment: Hey, wait a minute. My main equation is negative of what you're taken.

Comment: You are right. The integral is $I=\pm\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{x^4}{2}-x^2}}=\pm\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{2}-1}} $ and the substitution is $x=\sqrt{2}\sec\theta$. So, $I=\int d\theta=\theta+c_2$.